# How do I extrude this cylinder?

Tags: extrude

I'm a bit new to blender and I am trying to make a model, but I need to extrude the faces like this:

(The picture shows the inner cylinder)

[image: NoDescription]

I currently have this:

[image: NoDescription]

When I try to extrude, (I want all of the faces extruded, but to demonstrate I did one) it looks like this:

[image: NoDescription]

Then when I tried to move the edges a bit to look similar to the one in the picture, it ends up like this:

[image: NoDescription]

[image: NoDescription]

And I REALLY dont know how I'm gonna do that for ALL of the faces too, and I dont know how to make it 'symmetrical' so when I move the edges they both move inwards.

Sorry if formatting is terrible. Thanks.

Edit In response to Carlo:

Thanks for the reply, It's successful when I do it, but it turns out too wide for each one and ends up like this (and it also makes a part of it look wiered):

[image: NoDescription]

[image: NoDescription]

Is there any way to add more faces to it?

Edit 3: Response to Carlo again

[image]

Comment: The best you could do is add a mirror modifier. Then you could have at least two faces move at once. You could do two or three faces at one probably

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1) Keeping modifiers unapplied

Modeling without applying modifiers can be quite tricky.

Tring to keep the Solidify modifier, which basically extrude faces along their normals, isn't probably the best choiche for your task because your reference object has a different depth extrusion on one side.

[image]

You could have done that by stacking two Solidify modifiers, but unfortunately currently faces created by another modifier cannot be pickedlike in other software packages (3dsMax...). Probably, with a bit of work the closest thing you can get is something like this:

[image]

where I had to **Inset** faces and pick only a few of them manually in order to put them in a **Vertex group** which would allowed me to set a different **Factor** in the modifier for the object's faces.

[image]

From the Blender manual page of the [Solidify modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html?highlight=solidify);

> **Vertex Group**
>
> Only vertices in this group are solidified - their weights are multiplied by the thickness, so vertices with lower weights will be
>   less thick.

and

> **Factor**
>
> How much the vertex weights are taken into account.
>
> - On 0.0, vertices with zero weight will have no thickness at all.
> - On 0.5, vertices with zero weight will be half as thick as those with full weight.
> - On 1.0, the weights are ignored and the thickness value is used for every vertex.

[image]

To make the edges sligtly thinner toward the center you can work (for example) on the inner edges of the Full Weight faces:

[image]

---

### 2) Applying modifiers

If is suitable for the project, it's probably easier to apply the *Solidifiy* modifier it seems you are using (or extrude the faces inward as in the picture below)

[image]

then use the **Checker deselect tool** to pick one face every two and "**Extrude region (vertex normals)**" to build the gear tooth.

[image]

Pick the iner faces, set Individual origin Pivot, Normal orientation and then scale each faces along the Normal-X axis by pressing in sequence <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> followed by the wanted value.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this, but can you reply to my edit too?

Comment: Did you inset the faces? It seems you have inconsistent normals and overlapping faces.Have a look at the provided file for a topology reference.

Comment: I don't exactly get what you mean. Sorry new to blender. EDIT: I think I see what you mean now, but when I inset and extrude it looks weired like this (go to original post for picture)

Comment: If you would like to follow the first workflow I propose, I warn you that the surface is not quite right. Start with a new cylinder, [inset](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html) all faces individually (without extruding, that belongs to the second workflow), then pick some of them and create a vertex group. Then add the modifier and tweak parameters.

Comment: Ahh I think I see what you have done now. Thank you.

Comment: Also one last question, is it possible to make them slightly inward like in the very first picture?

Comment: I've added a possible way to achieve that for each workflow, but they are only two of the may possible ways. It really depends on the modeling puropose. As you can see, applying modifier gives the possibility to edit all the faces, making easier to perform certain operation all at once.